# iOS InAppPurchase - Restore with no transactions

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, version, restore

I made InAppPurchase in my application with build number (2.0.2). Later on sam version I made Restore and it is working just fine.
Later I tried to do Restore in same application but with build number less than (where I bought) and it returns 0 transactions.
I also tried to do restore on bigger build version (3.5.7) and it Restores successfully.

I should mention that this is the same app (same code) just different build number.

I tried to find anything about this on Google and in official Apple documentation, but no luck. Anyone has this issue? Any workaround or different approach to avoid this issue?

Comment: Let say you have 3 versions of your app (v1 earlier than v2 earlier than v3). If you create an IAP and release it for your v2, your customers will have access to it since this v2. If you don't remove this IAP, it will be available for further version (i.e. v2, v3, and later). User could not have bought the IAP from an earlier version than v2, so their no point restoring an IAP released in v2 to v1. It's just how I see that, I have no proof of what I'm saying.

Comment: I've created IAP product for version v1 and same stays (same product id) is for other version (v2 and v3). Product is not released at point v2.